# Calculate running average in a recursive SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a bit of code which calculates the current average row by row bases starting with receipt 1.

I have the below table which contains data for purchase quantity, price etc. I need to calculate the running average (current average) for each row starting from receipt 1. Receipt one is always easy because the previous price doesn't impact its average.

Once you have receipt 1 average (£75) you can use this to caluclate the subsequent rows.

I have manually calculated receipt 2 to be "£79.4858". I have been advised the best way it to use CTE recursive.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[X]
(
    [Item No_] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ReceiptNo] [bigint] NULL,
    [Sold] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
    [InventoryBalance] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseQty] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
    [IntakeSellingPrice] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
    [NewBalance] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
    [CurrentAverage] [numeric](2, 2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[X] ([Item No_], [ReceiptNo], [Sold], [InventoryBalance], [PurchaseQty], [IntakeSellingPrice], [NewBalance], [CurrentAverage]) 
VALUES (N'2000045', 1, CAST(0.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(0.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(500.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(75.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(500.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(0.00 AS Numeric(2, 2))),
       (N'2000045', 2, CAST(250.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(250.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(2181.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(80.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(2431.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(0.00 AS Numeric(2, 2))),
       (N'2000045', 3, CAST(316.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(2115.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(10.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(80.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(2125.00000000000000000000 AS Decimal(38, 20)), CAST(0.00 AS Numeric(2, 2)))
```

Comment: You need the running average of the `IntakeSellingPrice` column, right?

Comment: Average of what? You said the "Average" column receipt2 is £79.48, and the average of Recept 1 is £75. What numbers are you using for that? The average of £75.00 and £80.00 is £77.50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you are looking running avg like as below with the help of `lag()` function

```
select [Item No_],ReceiptNo,((PurchaseQty * IntakeSellingPrice) +  
           (InventoryBalance * isnull(lag(IntakeSellingPrice) over (order by [Item No_]), IntakeSellingPrice)
           ))/NewBalance [RunningAVG]
from X
```

Result :

```
Item No_    ReceiptNo   RunningAVG
2000045     1           75.000000
2000045     2           79.485808
2000045     3           80.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the cumulative average:

```
select x.*,
       avg(?) over (order by [Item No_]) as running_avg
from dbo.x;
```

The `?` is for the column you care about.  I can't tell which you want the running average for.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT *
      ,AVG([IntakeSellingPrice]) OVER (ORDER BY [Item No_] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM [dbo].[X]
```

Using a [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) clause and the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` will perform the aggregate over the all columns from the start to current row, where rows are ordered by the `ORDER BY` clause.